# Joint Probability Mass Function: Wiki definition question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Do the following definitions for the joint probability mass function appear correct?  I put this together from Wiki's [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution).

where $(X_n = x_n) = \{s \in \Omega : X(s) = x_n\}$

$$
f_{X_1, ..., X_n}(a_1, ..., a_n) = P(X_1 = a_1, ... , X_n = a_n) = P(\{s \in \Omega : X_1(s) = a_1 \land \, ... \,  \land X_n(s) = a_n\}) = P(\{s \in \Omega : X_1(s) = a_1\} \cap ... \cap \{s \in \Omega : X_n(s) = a_n\}
$$

Comment: What do you call a Bernoulli process ? What would that lead to different mutually exclusive events ?

Comment: I removed the Bernoulli Process.  I'm interested if the definition and equality above is correct

Comment: I don't understand the second line (why is there some wedge ?), but otherwise it seems good.

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois the second line $\land$ is the logical **and** function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. This is just a straightforward application of the definition. Note that, if $X_1, X_2$ are two independent Bernoulli random variables of parameter $\frac12$ (which I suspect was what you meant at first), you have, because of the independence,
that knowing that $s \in \Omega$ is such that $X_1(s) = 1$ tells you nothing about $X_2(s)$. Basically in this case you can see your $\Omega$ as $\{(s_i,t_i), i\in \{1,2\}$ with $X_1((s_i,t_i)) = \delta_{s_i,s_1}$ and $X_2((s_i,t_i)) = \delta_{t_i,t_1}$.
Hence
\begin{equation} \mathbb{P}(\{s \in \Omega: X_1(s) = 1\} \cap \{ s \in \Omega: X_2(s) = 1\}) = \mathbb{P}(\{s \in \Omega: X_1(s) = 1\}) \mathbb{P}(\{s \in \Omega: X_2(s) = 1\}). 
\end{equation}
and you can check this manually using the particular form of $\Omega$ that I provided above.